# WPF: How to turn Off Snaplines?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013

I am creating simple wpf app with controls located in StackPanel.
all I need is to turn off snaplines and arrange spacing between controls how I want.

Is there a way to do it ? 
(except holding alt key which did not work also as it has 'duplicate control' function in my VS)

In XAML editor there is "Turn on snapping to snaplines" option but it does not work ! I am still unable to position controls freely.

Comment: Switch to XAML mode, you can do whatever you want there.

Comment: Well, fix the real problem and get rid of that "duplicate control function".

Comment: In XAML editor there is "Turn on snapping to snaplines" option but it does not work ! I am still unable to position controls freely.

Comment: Quite far from the answer, but IMHO the StackPanel is everything but the right container for visually placing the children controls.

Comment: ok so is there any suggestion how to place controls on a form and have border around them ?

Comment: XAML is designed to stop you from positioning controls where you want them. E.g. I can set Canvas.Top="45"  and Canvas.Top="5" and the control appears in the EXACT same place. This is one of many things I give out about and get down-votes for. Exact positioning is something that programmers and their customers want but Microsoft continue to ignore the issue. Guess they are too busy playing with their AI and cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to change StackPanel to Grid control !